# SqlBulkCopy and EF - Error: "The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination"

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sqlbulkcopy

I've tried everything sugested in related questions but I'm still having this error.

This is my entity class:

```
public class Activity
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int Minute { get; set; }
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public int LectureId { get; set; }
    public virtual Lecture Lecture { get; set; }
}
```

And this the content of the repository method responsible to do the SqlBulkCopy:

```
var sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlBulkCopy sbCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
        {
            sbCopy.DestinationTableName = "Activity";
            var table = objs.ToDataTable();
            sbCopy.ColumnMappings.Clear();
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                sbCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(col.ColumnName.Trim(), col.ColumnName.Trim()));       

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                sbCopy.BatchSize = 48;;

                await sbCopy.WriteToServerAsync(table);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

And, finally, the `ToDataTable` code:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.CaseSensitive = true;

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);

        foreach (T item in collection)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

I need to save thousands of rows and EF is very slow. Any sugestions?

Comment: only if you're available to create your own temporary SQL table, utilize temporary table rather than Entity. It's really satisfying.

Comment: Check the generated `DataTable` columns. I suspect you need to exclude navigation properties like `Lecture`.

Comment: @IvanStoev is correct

Comment: Thank you, @IvanStoev!
It's working now.